# Should Azure ServiceBusConnection be singleton?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

In the **old** NuGet, it was good practice to retain the `MessagingFactory` instance.

Should we retain a single instance of `ServiceBusConnection` (from **new** Nuget) to be injected into multiple clients?

EDIT 2018-07-25 00:22:00 UTC+8:

- added a bit of clarity that ServiceBusConnection is from new NuGet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not necessarily a singleton for all.

The right level of grain is the Messaging Factory. You may connect to a number of namespaces in your application, each will require their own [MessageFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.messagingfactory?view=azure-dotnet) and connection.

Alternatively you may have code that is not very async in it's nature and in this instance multiples connections (factories) make sense. For example you have two processes in your code, one that does a lot of work in a loop to send messages and another that receives, in this case two factories may be useful or you may refactor to make your code more async.

[From the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-performance-improvements#reusing-factories-and-clients).

> It is recommended that you do not close messaging factories or queue,
>   topic, and subscription clients after you send a message, and then
>   re-create them when you send the next message. Closing a messaging
>   factory deletes the connection to the Service Bus service.

In short, you should be re-using your message factories, which then maintain a connection to the service bus. Depending on how your code is written you may want to have multiple factories.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-performance-improvements#reusing-factories-and-clients

Comment: Thanks for replying.
I did lookup this best practice documentation. However, MessageFactory is part of the old library (Microsoft.ServiceBus) and the rest of the document also pointed to the old library. Factory does not exist in the new library (Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus). The clients now accept either connection string or ServiceBusConnection instance hence my question.

Comment: For the 3.0 library it appears it is all managed through the QueueClient, one for each queue, so I would use that level of granularity as a reference. If you need to continually send and/or receive messages, then I would create a client and keep it open with a guard to reconnect if it has closed / failed. If you need to do a few operations and then some other long running code, I'd create a client, do the work then close it until the next "batch" is needed.

Answer (score 3):

Azure Service Bus .NET Standard client connections are not managed via `QueueClient` or any factory, like its predecessor used to. `QueueClient` is an abstraction on top of `MessageSender` and `MessageReceiver` that can take a `ServiceBusConnection` shared by multiple senders/receivers. You're free to choose either to share the same connection object or not.

```
var connection = new ServiceBusConnection(connectionString);
var queueClient1 = new QueueClient(connection, "queue1", ReceiveMode.PeekLock, RetryPolicy.Default);
var queueClient2 = new QueueClient(connection, "queue2", ReceiveMode.PeekLock, RetryPolicy.Default);
// Queue clients share the same connection
var message1 = new Message(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Message1"));
var message2 = new Message(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Message2"));
```

Based on the namespace tier you're using, you'll have to benchmark and see what works better for you. My findings showed that with Standard tier having multiple connections helps throughput, while with Premium tier it doesn't. [This post](https://weblogs.asp.net/sfeldman/what-you-pay-is-what-you-get) hints at the reasons why it's so.